# Using view() function in R

Tags: r

Which package do I need to install in order to run the function "view" ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpnQr.png)

Comment: You should use `View`，V is uppercase letter.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the help page using "??view" (or for any other function you're interested in). Scrolling down and selecting the right page, this will show that

1. `View` must be capitalized
2. `View` is part of the `utils` package, a part of base R (so you don't need to install a new one)